# Joining tables with references to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK. So as I'm writing this query, I realize it's unlike any other I've written because of the table structure. Two of three tables I'm trying to bring together have references to *both* of the others, *and* one of said references is nullable.

```
Table A: aID (PK), etc  
Table B: bID (PK), aID (FK), etc  
Table C: cID, aID (FK), bID (nullable FK), etc
```

In my query, I'm trying to locate all `A` and `B` rows that are not referenced in a `C` row.

I've tried all sorts of stuff, the least of which was right joins, which I don't particularly enjoy. I also contemplated some sort of `JOIN ON x AND y` - but I'm not clear on what that does, and documentation is scarce.

**E.G.**

Table A

```
aID
1
2
3
```

Table B

```
bID     aID
1       1
2       1
3       2
```

Table C

```
cID aID bID
1   1   NULL
2   1   1
3   2   NULL
```

Query should return

```
aID bID
1   2
2   3
3   NULL
```

Comment: Any time you see a right join it can be re-written as a left - you just need to switch the ordering of the tables in the FROM clause.

Comment: Also, it would be great to see some sample data and desired results to help clarify your request!

Comment: There are several ways of doing this, depending on what exactly you need. Can you please add some sample data and the expected outcome the query should produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cab do it like this:

```
SELECT A.aID, B.bID
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.aID=B.aID -- We are not guaranteed to have B for each A
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.aID=A.aID AND (C.bID IS NULL OR C.bID=B.bID)
WHERE C.cID IS NULL
```

**Note:** Edited in response to a comment.

Comment: Thing is, we're not guaranteed to have a B for every A, so that leaves me in the dark about whether or not the A rows exist.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to locate all A and B rows that are not referenced in a C
>   row.

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.aID, B.bID
FROM A INNER JOIN B
  ON A.aID = B.aID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM C
   WHERE A.aID = C.aID OR B.bID = C.bID 
)
```

`Not Exists` is the preferred way since it has no issues with null values on the join-column. [Read](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

---

If not every a-row has a b-row but you want to see the a-row anyway(as mentioned in a comment to the other answer), you have to use an `Outer Join`:

```
SELECT A.aID, B.bID
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON A.aID = B.aID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ... (rest same)
```